# Cookie in sub folder not being written

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I am able to access cookie value on page present inside a sub folder of root directory which set inside another page present in another subfolder of my application.

```
Dim pageNum as String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("PageNumber").Value
```

But when i try to write value to this cookie on same page present inside a sub folder of root directory
the value does not get replaced

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("PageNumber").Value = newPageNum
```

How to write cookie value if page is present inside a subfolder ? Whats the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should use response to write a cookie instead request try:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("PageNumber");
myCookie.Value = newPageNum;
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

for more reference look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287547(VS.71).aspx)